# glibc memory corruption with libmysqlcppconn prepared statement

Tags: c++, mysql, linux, memory

I'm currently writing a web-crawler/spider in C++ on Linux and I'm having some problems with updating a database. I'm *fairly* new to C/C++, just FYI.

The database updates are executed by a seperate thread (using pthreads) but the same problem exists if executed in main() so I, perhaps naively, discarded the threading stuff as the cause of anything.

I'm using [libmysqlcppconn](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Connector_C%2B%2B) for the database API.

I am compiling with gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) with -O2 -Wall -pedantic and it compiles cleanly.

Nevertheless, when the function commitChangesToDatabase() below is called, it basically picks out items from a std::map (url_queue), throws them in a std::vector (updates) and erases said item from the original std::map, then proceeds to iterate over the std::vector, executing a MySQL prepared statement for each item in the vector. Here is where it fails hard.

It randomly either:

- Crashes without any error output (no segfault, no stacktrace, no nothing)
- Crashes with a glibc memory corruption detected (see output here: http://pastie.org/private/wlkuorivq5tptlcr7ojg)
- Reports that the MySQL server has gone away (caught exception), but keeps trying (doesn't crash)

I have tried switching the prepared statement to a simple executeUpdate(), but to no avail.
I have tried eliminating the step with picking out items and rather just execute the updates whenever I find an item to update, in the first loop over url_queue.

Other functions in this application uses prepared statements as well (another UPDATE) and that works fine. Those functions are also run by seperate threads.

I would run the application through valgrind, but quite frankly, I don't understand most of the output so it wouldn't help me much - but if anyone wants the output from it, let me know which options to run it with and I'll provide it.

I have no clue how to proceed from here. Anyone have a clue what's wrong?

```
struct queue_item_t {
    int id;
    int sites_id;
    int priority;
    int depth;
    int handler;
    int state;  // 0 = Pending, 1 = Working, 2 = Completed, 3 = Checked
    double time_allowed_crawl;

    bool status;
    bool was_redirected;

    double time;
    double time_end;
    double time_curl;
    double size;

    std::string hash;
    std::string url;
    std::string file;
    std::string host;
};

void commitChangesToDatabase()
{
    map< string, queue_item_t >::iterator it, end;
    sql::PreparedStatement *pstmt;
    int i = 0;

    if (!url_queue.size()) {
        return;
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&dbCommitMutex);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&itemMutex);

    cout << "commitChangesToDatabase()" << endl;
    pstmt = dbPrepareStatement("UPDATE crawler_queue SET process_hash = NULL, date_crawled = NOW(), url = ?, hash = ? WHERE id = ?");

    for (it = url_queue.begin(); it != url_queue.end();)
    {
        if (it->second.state == 2)
        {
            pstmt->setString(1, it->second.url);
            pstmt->setString(2, it->second.hash);
            pstmt->setInt(3, it->second.id);

            try {
                pstmt->executeUpdate();
                ++i;

            } catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
                cerr << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
                cerr << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " << __LINE__ << endl;
                cerr << "# ERR: " << e.what();
                cerr << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
                cerr << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
            }

            url_queue.erase(it++);
        }
        else {
            ++it;
        }
    }

    delete pstmt;

    cout << "~commitChangesToDatabase()" << endl;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&itemMutex);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&dbCommitMutex);
}

// this function is defined in another file but is written here just to show the contents of it
sql::PreparedStatement *dbPrepareStatement(const std::string &query)
{
    return con->prepareStatement(query);
}
```

Edit:

Some seem to believe the problem is with the iteration over the url_queue collection, however I have ruled that out but commenting out everything that operates on the database, but not the iteration. Furthermore, the iteration here is a simplified (but working) version of the original which picks out items from the map, throws in a vector and erases from the map, as demonstrated below, and that part of the program works fine - it *only* crashes whenever the database is used.

```
for (it = url_queue.begin(); it != url_queue.end();)
{
    if (it->second.state == 2)
    {
        update_item.type = (!it->second.was_redirected ? 1 : 2);
        update_item.item = it->second;

        updates.push_back(update_item);

        url_queue.erase(it++);
    }
    else {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

Edit 2:

Output from `valgrind --leak-check=yes`: http://pastie.org/private/2ypk0bmawwsqva3ikfazw

Comment: Can you add the declaration of `queue_item_t` to your question?

Comment: Also, you should not erase items from a collection you are iterating over. It may invalidate the iterator. Also, you always increase the iterator twice, is that intentional jumping over every second item?

Comment: I found the method of erasing from a collection that you're iterating over here on StackOverflow which suggested to evaluate .begin() and .end() of the collection every iteration. Sorry, the double-increase was a mistake that didn't affect the problem - the ++it in the for(;;) shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, the iterator is incremented unnecessarily; first in loop body, and also in for statement. In this code, it is possible to increment the `end`  iterator, this is a problematic operation and might be source of the problem.

The following loop structure is more suitable for this case: 
    `it = url_queue.begin();` 
    `while( it != url_queue.end() ){
       //loop body
    }`

Comment: I just edited my question to show that this isn't the problem, as I have already ruled out this part of the program to be the culpri.

Comment: OK then. I have two more notes, not sure if they are applicable. First; it is good practice to check output of `conn->prepareStatement()` which may fail but you can still use it. Second: `url_queue.size()` should be inside the mutex protected block.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a good idea to mess with iterators. replace:

```
else {
        ++it;
    }
```

by:

```
else continue;
```

or just remove it.

Comment: As I wrote in my first edit of my question, the iterator logic works - valgrind doesn't show any problems with that, only errors from the database API - but it works in other areas in the application which I why I am clueless as to why it doesn't work in this function. Incrementing the iterator is the only way to advance it to the next element, as I understand it.